# File path in c++

Tags: c++, file, dll, path

I am doing a project that involves files and DLLs and am working on different computers. so whenever I transfer my work to another PC I have to change the file path and the DLL's path. is there any way to avoid that??

Comment: Setup the same directory strcuture. That's how I usually do it. If possible use relative paths. In Visual Studio you can also use predefined variables.

Comment: Thank you all for your help .... I have used the $(SolutionDir) macro, as well as the .. operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using absolute paths (like C:\MyProjects\Project1 ...etc) try using the macros such as $(SolutionDir)\MyDllsDir

Answer (score 1):

**Use relative paths.** That's what they are there for! Never hard-code absolute paths into your projects or code.